# Trigger cancellation of Azure build pipeline from code from c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I'm building an azure function that works as a approval checker for azure builds to be deployed, in the image below, you can see how it's being called for a pipeline that is trying to deploy.

[image: Approval checker]

What I need to do in C#, in some scenarios, is to CANCEL the pipeline that is calling my function to stop it from calling.
What I'm thinking to use is a PATCH method that Azure itself uses to cancel them, but I don't know how to call it with the proper headers and payload
This is what gets called when you hit the CANCEL button in a pipeline:
[image: Cancel patch in network]

I'm building a request with a HTTPClient with this address, what else should I send as a param or header to make it work?

```
var _baseAddress = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/myprojectname/");
var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, new Uri(_baseAddress, $"{myProjectId}/_apis/build/builds/{buildRunId}"));
var serializedDoc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = 4 });
msg.Content = new StringContent(serializedDoc, Encoding.UTF8);
msg.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
msg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json-patch+json");
var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(msg);
```

I could not find any other similar question or implementation, so any answer is welcome

Comment: For all interactions with Azure you will need to provide a bearer token (SPN or UPN related) in the Authorization header for the call to succeed

Comment: How can I get that bearer token from? Where should I authenticate my app? For what I've done so far. everything is in place but the token

Comment: There are many ways to obtain tokens, this is one of them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token